# ckeditor allowedExtraContent with closing html tag

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I have issues to configure my ckEditor.

The configuration looks like that :

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready( function() {
    var ckeditor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'myTest', {
            allowedContent: true
            extraAllowedContent : 'foo[*]{*}'
</script>
```

And the HTML is :

```
<textarea id="myTest">
  <foo>balabalabal</foo>
  <foo attr="value"/>
</textarea>
```

When I looked at the result in my browser the second foo tag if missing,
how can I keep both of them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember that CKEditor is an HTML editor and there's no `<foo>` tag. Additionally, you created one closed `<foo></foo>` tag and one self-closing `<foo />`. You cannot load such content into CKEditor.

Note that it is possible to tune CKEditor a little bit to accept non-HTML tags. This can be achieved by extending the [`CKEDITOR.dtd`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd) object.

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.foo = { '#': 1 };
CKEDITOR.dtd.body.foo = 1;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$block.foo = 1;
```

This will allow `foo` tags as children of `body`. `foo` tag will be allowed to have text content only (`'#'`) and will be treated as a block tag.

Comment: Hi, 
First, I know the no such tag in HTML, but those tags are used in PHP to display particular content.
I already manage to keep the <foo>bar</foo> tag by adding the extraAllowedContent line.
The thing most of those tags are self-closing and ckeditor remove my self-closing tag. I need to keep them, to parse them in PHP after.

Comment: You cannot use `<foo>` as a self-closing tag and tag with content at the same time. No way to force CKEditor to accept this.